# Checking if a sequence container is contiguous in memory

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, c++14, type-traits

Is there a way to check if a sequence container is contiguous in memory? Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_contiguous<std::vector<int>>::value   << '\n'  // true
    std::cout << is_contiguous<std::deque<int>>::value    << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << is_contiguous<std::array<int, 3>>::value << '\n'; // true
}
```

**Clarification**

This question is referring to type traits, rather than the properties of a specific instance of a type.

Comment: Not at this point. The term "contiguous iterator" is only defined as an editorial tool to make the specification more compact, but it's not a queriable trait.

Comment: You may still create a custom traits with all the required specializations...

Comment: @BaummitAugen Possible use case could be for extracting stream input into templated sequence container. With a contiguous container, `std::basic_istream::getline` can be used directly (e.g. `in.getline(&container[0], 10)`).

Comment: @Daniel: That's what the fake iterators like `insert_iterator` are for

Comment: The existence of `.data()` returning a pointer might be a reasonable proxy.

Comment: @T.C. That seems to be the best solution without better language support.

Comment: @Daniel I think you have an answer: a resounding 'no'. Regardless of whether or not you _like_ the answer, you should still accept one. It seems based on comments that TemplateRex's answer was most helpful.

Comment: @T.C. , I agree that yours is the best solution. Do you know if a similar trick can be applied to checking if an iterator is contiguous? (I personally think that for consistency, iterators with contiguous access should themselves have a `.data()` member or a `data(ContIt)` function).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**, there is not compiletime trait for this.

The [**draft C++1z Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) defines contiguity as a **runtime property** of an iterator range. Note there is no compiletime `std::contiguous_iterator_tag` corresponding to this iterator category.

> **24.2 Iterator requirements [iterator.requirements]**
>
> **24.2.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]**
>
> 5 Iterators that further satisfy the requirement that, for integral
>   values `n` and dereferenceable iterator values `a` and `(a + n), *(a + n)`
>   is equivalent to `*(addressof(*a) + n)`, are called contiguous
>   iterators. [ Note: For example, the type “pointer to int” is a
>   contiguous iterator, but `reverse_iterator<int *>` is not. For a valid
>   iterator range `[a,b)` with dereferenceable `a`, the corresponding range
>   denoted by pointers is `[addressof(*a),addressof(*a) + (b - a));` `b`
>   might not be dereferenceable. — end note ]

One way to test for this at runtime would be

```
#include <array>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

template<class I>
auto is_contiguous(I first, I last)
{ 
    auto test = true;
    auto const n = std::distance(first, last);
    for (auto i = 0; i < n && test; ++i) {
        test &= *(std::next(first, i)) == *(std::next(std::addressof(*first), i));
    }        
    return test;        
}

int main()
{
    auto l = std::list<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto m = std::map<int, int>  { {1, 1}, {2,2}, {3,3} };
    auto u = std::unordered_multiset<int> { 1, 1, 1 };
    auto d = std::deque<int>(4000);
    int c[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto a = std::array<int, 3> {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
    auto s = std::string {"Hello world!"};
    auto v = std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3, };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(l.begin(), l.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(m.begin(), m.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(u.begin(), u.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(d.begin(), d.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(d.begin(), d.begin() + 1000) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(std::begin(c), std::end(c)) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(a.begin(), a.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(s.begin(), s.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_contiguous(v.rbegin(), v.rend()) << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0e37d9aa7f8c305). This prints `false` for the `list`, `map` and `unordered_multimap`, and `true` for the C-array, and the `std::array`, `string` and `vector`. It prints `true` for small subranges within a `deque` and `false` for large subranges. It also prints `false` for an iterator range consisting of reverse iterators.

**UPDATE**: as commented by @T.C. the original [**N3884**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3884.pdf) proposal did have a

```
struct contiguous_iterator_tag : random_access_iterator_tag {};
```

so that tag-dispatching on iterator categories would not break. However, this would have broken non-idiomatic code with class template specializations on `random_access_iterator_tag`. The current draft hence does not contain a new iterator category tag.

Comment: You forgot to mention that contiguous iterators as an iterator category are not part of any released standard yet. So for C++11 and C++14, this concept is not queryable by traits or something else.

Comment: Also noteworthy is that `std::deque` will return true until reaching a certain size, then will subsequently return false.

Comment: @ildjarn updated with tests for `deque` (small and big subrange) and also for reverse iterators.

Comment: @Jens updated to reflect that this is a C++1z feature. Note that it is not a compiletime but a runtime property of iterator ranges.

Comment: @TemplateRex It seems a shame to me that it's defined that way; I can't think of a good reason why this can't - and shouldn't - be compile time decidable.

Comment: @Daniel it would require quite a lot of infrastructure, and would also depend on the allocator. E.g one can imagine an allocator that puts list nodes in contiguous memory, but only if the amount of nodes is smaller than a certain number, and fall back to the heap otherwise (Howard Hinnant's [stack allocator e.g.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)). So this seems to be a quintessential runtime property. Also the example for `deque` shows that it depends on the iterators whether a subrange within a container is contiguous.

Comment: The original proposal would have added a `contiguous_iterator_tag`, but ended up not doing it because it would break existing code.

Comment: @T.C. true, but that still would have left `deque` a bit in the lurch.

Answer (score 7):

No. The C++ Standard guarantees there are no false negatives. (i.e., `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::array`, and basic arrays are promised to be stored contiguously).

However, the C++ Standard *doesn't* guarantee there are no false positives.

```
int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<Node> n1(new Node);
   std::unique_ptr<Node> n2(new Node);
   n1->next = n2; // n1 and n2 might be contiguous, but might not be
}
```

Thus, your type trait could be wrong some of the time. If it's wrong some of the time, it's not a type trait; rather, it's an instance trait.

Comment: A trait implemented like this would be unusable anyway for any container with zero or one elements in it. Probably why nobody's suggested it. So we're back to just "no": the only way such a trait could exist would be built in to the standard library, and one is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right. The only naïve implementation would be to check if it's a `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::string` or basic array; but that is so flimsy that I didn't even want to add it to my answer.

Comment: But is that really false? If I verify that every element other than the first in a container is adjacent to the previous element, then is not *that particular container at that moment* contiguous? (And I know it won't change if I make no changes to the container.)

Comment: What if I "prove" that it is all contiguous, then add an element that isn't, then use a method that relies on all contiguous elements?

Comment: @rici: Yes but that would be a property of your container instance, not a trait of its type. And, therefore, not what was asked for.

Comment: @lightness: the op asks about a container, which is at best ambiguous. I think the more natural interpretation is that it asks about a container, rather than a class which lets you create containers. But your interpretation is also valid.

Comment: @erip: that would be just as undefined as modifying a container in the middle of a range for over the container.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, but I'm not willing to argue. :)

Comment: @lightness: actually, looking at the examples in the OP, I can see the strength of your interpretation.

Comment: I disagree. While an "is this container's data stored contiguously?" type trait is impossible, an "is this container's data **guaranteed to be** stored contiguously?" is quite reasonable and could be useful.

Comment: @erip: it's the kind of question which invites devil's advocacy :-)

Comment: @immibis That's not what OP asked.

Comment: @immibis In any case, I've already addressed how one might implement a "guaranteed-to-be-contiguous" trait in my comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh no, it seems some of your downvotes have leaked over to me. ;)

Comment: @erip: Haha there's just no justice any more

Comment: @erip I don't how immibis's interpretation is different to what I've asked;  data contiguity is a trait of the type if and only if the data of any instance of that type is (guaranteed to be) contiguous.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, and that's what I've addressed. The only types that are ever guaranteed to be contiguous are `std::vector`, `srd::array`, `std::string`, and basic array. There's a huge difference between an instance being contiguous and a type being contiguous.

Answer (score -4):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: What if I posted "yes"?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I would ask you to prove it. When you have the benefit of being correct and say no, there's not much to prove other than to say "check out the standard - it's not in there."

Comment: @WaiHaLee: I cannot prove a negative. The question is broken, really.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, you _can_ prove a negative. Two typical ways are providing absence of evidence (i.e., mentioned above: it's not the standard) or providing a proof of impossibility (my answer). People don't like simple answers.

Comment: @erip - Absence of evidence doesn't prove a negative.

Comment: Yikes, I meant evidence of absence.