# How to detect if a container is guaranteed to have sequence storage

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

[Checking if a sequence container is contiguous in memory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004633/checking-if-a-sequence-container-is-contiguous-in-memory)
[C++ templates that accept only certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

I am writing a simple `send()` method, which internally works with C-style pointers. I would like it to be able to work with all the guaranteed sequence containers. My motivation being twofold:

- a flexible interface
- efficiency - using `std::array` avoids heap allocations.

Here is how far I am:

```
template <typename Container>
void poll( Container &out )
{
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< std::array<typename Container::value_type>, Container >::value  ||
                   std::is_base_of< std::vector<typename Container::value_type>, Container >::value ||
                   std::is_base_of< std::string<typename Container::value_type>, Container >::value,
                   "A contiguous memory container is required.");
}
```

Trouble is, `std::array` requires a second parameter, and that cannot be known at compile time. Is this problem solvable? Possibly by a different approach?

Comment: Or just add an overload. (Which is why you can't partially specialize functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way here is to use a trait class. `std::is_base_of` is a kind of trait. Basically: You have a templated struct that takes a (template) param and returns its result via a nested type/value.

In your case something like this

```
template<typename T>
struct HasContiguousStorage: public std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct HasContiguousStorage<std::vector<T>>: public std::true_type{};
// Specialize others
```

As you should not derive from standard containers, this should be enough. This can also check for the array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct HasContiguousStorage<std::array<T,N>>: public std::true_type{};
```

In your function you can then either overload it (see `enable_if`) or branch on it (branch will be evaluated at compile-time)

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about those.

Answer (score 7):

How about if the container has a `data()` member function? (that returns a pointer)

Comment: Nah, std::string returns `const char*`. It appears my pre-conditions have been untrue.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot do it yet, I am in the process of updating [n4183 Contiguous Iterators: Pointer Conversion & Type Trait](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4183.pdf) for (hopeful) inclusion in a future C++ standard.