# Why does std::is_array return false for std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, type-traits

Since `std::array<>` and `std::is_array<>` were both introduced in C++11, it seems very strange that this fails to compile:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_array<std::array<int,2>>::value);
```

Is there a simple way to check if something is an array, including both the possibilities of `T[N]` and `std::array<T,N>`?

Comment: `std::array` simply isn't an array. They just called it that because it's a more convenient name than something like `std::array_wrapper` or `std::better_array`.

Comment: @user2357112: Since the meaning of `is_array<>` was decided by precisely the same version of the same language which defined `array<>`, the notion that "array isn't an array" seems absurd, doesn't it?

Comment: The smart pointers don't pass `is_pointer`, either. `std::is_array` would be less useful if it special-cased `std::array`, and making `std::array` an actual array would defeat the whole point of making `std::array` in the first place. Just don't let the names confuse you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004633/checking-if-a-sequence-container-is-contiguous-in-memory

Comment: Given that `std::array` were introduced, a better name would have been `std::is_carray`. But traits are messy really and play by their own rules, and quirky names. For example, according to `std`, `std::complex<double>` is not `arithmetic`. (`std::is_arithmetic<std::complex<double>>` is false). I think this is because getting "concepts" right is difficult even simple one. I expect more problems like this to appear with Concepts in the language where things will not mean exactly what they seem all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::is_array` is defined to be true only for types that look like `T[]` or `T[N]`.  `std::array` is not included.

You cannot modify or specialize `std::is_array` to be `true_type` for `std::array` under the standard; that would make your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  When specializing types within `std`, the result must be consistent with the standard, and the standard is specific here.  (Also, doing so for other templates within `std` is highly questionable to illegal).

You can create your own `is_array` trait:

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class T>
  struct is_array:std::is_array<T>{};
  template<class T, std::size_t N>
  struct is_array<std::array<T,N>>:std::true_type{};
  // optional:
  template<class T>
  struct is_array<T const>:is_array<T>{};
  template<class T>
  struct is_array<T volatile>:is_array<T>{};
  template<class T>
  struct is_array<T volatile const>:is_array<T>{};
}
```

then use `notstd::is_array<T>` elsewhere to detect either C-style arrays or C++ `std::array`.

Answer (score 5):

ISO/IEC 14882:2011, § 20.9.4.1, Table 47 says this:

- Template: template  struct is_array;
- Condition: T is an array type (3.9.2) of known or unknown extent
- Comment: Class template array (23.3.2) is not an array type.

so, the assertion should fail.

Although you could specialize the `is_array` as proposed by @0x499602D2, if you did that you should do so in another namespace, as you should not attempt to change the meaning of standardized functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Couldn't code that wanted to distinguish C++ arrays from C arrays use `std::is_class<>`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes, it could. I suppose the standard writers thought it would be more useful this way

Comment: @harmic Your last paragraph results in an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required; specializations of traits classes within the `std` namespace must not violate the axioms of the traits class as documented in the standard.

Comment: @Yakk, I'm not sure what you mean there as my last paragraph was suggestion that you *should not* try to do that. Anyway I've tightened up the wording a little.

Comment: This should have been called `std::is_c_array`, not unlike `c_str()`. Right now it is borderline embarrassing and borderline unexplainable to a newcomer, why a construct, explicitly called "array" is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Cppreference provides this possible implementation:

```
template<class T>
struct is_array : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_array<T[]> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array<T[N]> : std::true_type {};
```

It doesn't provide a specialization for `std::array` unfortunately. You can make your own by doing this:

```
template<class T>
struct is_array : std::is_array<T> {};
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: The workaround feels a bit dicey.. could break third party library-in-header code depending on the include order

Comment: @M.M Then what do you suggest? Making a specialization directly inside `std`?

Comment: I'd suggest understanding that `std::is_array` refers to C-style arrays only, not `std::array`  , and if you want a trait that matches both of those things then make your own trait

Comment: @M.M Great. You should make an answer then.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Place your `is_array` in `namespace notstd` or something; and make it clear it doesn't go in `std`.  As written, it is unclear if you are suggesting someone put it in the root namespace, their own namespace, or inject it into `std` or something equally horrible.